# Is there an action/hook for a user Activate button (under Users) in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, hook, action

Is there an action/hook when we Activate a User on Users menu:
[image]

Both profile_update and personal_options_update doesn't work when we hit the button !

Comment: Have you tried the endpoints for it? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/

If you open the console, does it throw errors when hitting the button?

Comment: Is this button added by a plugin? Can you provide an example href URL from this button?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on system with lesser permissions (<Admin) you're probably not going to be able to amend those attributes. I know, duh.

Issues with hosting aside... I use plugins like BuddyBoss And ContactList for a lot of sub-member management, where SSO is disabled in Wordpress.com hosting sites. There are publishing tools like Oasis Workflow ...